# What is the sense of converting PVOID buffer to PCHAR?

Tags: c++, c, memory-alignment

I see next code in the MS code examples:

```
PVOID alignedBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE/sizeof( PVOID )];
PCHAR buffer = (PCHAR) alignedBuffer;

hResult = FilterSendMessage( context->Port,
                                 &commandMessage,
                                 sizeof( COMMAND_MESSAGE ),
                                 buffer,
                                 sizeof(alignedBuffer),
                                 &bytesReturned );
```

(alignedBuffer will hold the array of structures that are passed as replay  to FilterSendMessage call)
What is the sense of  converting PVOID to PCHAR, does this helps with aligment, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not converting `PVOID` to `PCHAR`. You are converting an array of `PVOID`s (decaying to a `PVOID *`) to `PCHAR`.

```
PVOID alignedBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE/sizeof( PVOID )];
```

This defines `alignedBuffer` as an array of `PVOID`s (or `void *`s). As an array of pointers, it will be suitably aligned (usually 4-bytes on 32-bit, 8 bytes on 64-bit). If you do simply

```
CHAR buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

There's no similar guarantee, since there's no alignment requirement for `CHAR`s.

Comment: And  am i converting  array of PVOID to PCHAR and not to PVOID or LPVOID, (FilterSendMessage buffer parametr type is LPVOID), just a matter of taste?

Comment: @BransDs I suspect that converting it to `PCHAR` instead of `PVOID` might help with reading output from the buffer, since you can't dereference a void pointer, but otherwise it's an issue of taste.